# “it would not be fair to everyone else for me to eat all the oranges.”

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

> “it would not be fair to everyone else for me to eat all the oranges.”

Is that correct? Why there is "FOR", would it  not work simply with "WHEN"?

> “it would not be fair to everyone else when/if I eat all the oranges.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When I eat all the oranges* implies that event is a certainty<sup>1</sup>. Because you **will** eat all the oranges, it's not correct to start the sentence with the verb *would*, as that implies uncertainty.

> It will not be fair to everyone when I eat all the oranges.

Both *if I ate* (or *if I were to eat* or *if I was to eat*) and *for me to eat* are compatible with the implied uncertainty of *would*.

---

<sup>1</sup> That is, it is not the same as the German *wenn,* which translates as *if*.